# Gitlab How do I collect metrics such as how many issues users have opened and how many they have closed?

Tags: gitlab, prometheus

Gitlab How do I collect metrics such as how many issues users have opened and how many they have closed?

I have 40 users in Gitlab. I want to measure the performance of these users. How can I collect this data with prometheus and visualise it with grafana? Or is there any other way?

Comment: GitLab has a [REST API for issues](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html) that you could use.

Comment: What is the way to do this? Is there a tutorial?

Comment: There is the documentation, which is pretty good. Also there are some [third-party libraries](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/rest/#third-party-clients) you could use.